# 400 Bad Request and illegal invocation in wp_ajax based on processData set to false or true

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, ajax, wp-admin

As Salamu Alaikum,
I am working `wp_ajax` and try to upload a file through ajax. When I `processData: true` it returns error `illegal invocation` on file upload. But when I set `processData: false` it returns error `400 bad request`. But, I have double-checked that everything is fine in PHP. **But if I do not upload file all data get saved successfully**.

Here is my form...

```
 <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
            <input id="f-title" name="f-title" placeholder="Flyer Title" class="form-control" required="" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <input id="f-validity" name="f-validity" placeholder="Valid Till" class="form-control" required="" type="date">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <input id="f-ID" name="f-ID" placeholder="Flyer ID" class="form-control" required="" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <input id="f-thumbnail" name="f-thumbnail" class="form-control" required="" type="file">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <input id="f-company" name="f-company" class="form-control" placeholder="Company ID" required="" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <select id="f-category" name="f-category" class="form-control" required="">
            <?php 
                $limit = 50;
                $terms = apply_filters( 
                    'taxonomy-images-get-terms',  
                    '',
                    array( 
                        'taxonomy' => 'flyer-cat',
                    ) 
                );
                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                  $term_link = get_term_link( $term );

                }
            ?>
            <?php foreach($terms as $term) { ?>
                <?php $term_link = get_term_link( $term ); $limit++; ?>
                <option><?php _e($term->name); ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <button class="form-control" name="f-submit" id="f-submit" type="button">Save Flyer</button>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Here is my javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    jQuery('#f-submit').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var f_title = jQuery('#f-title').val();
      var f_validity = jQuery('#f-validity').val();
      var f_ID = jQuery('#f-ID').val();
      var f_company = jQuery('#f-company').val();
      var f_category = jQuery('#f-category').val();
      var f_thumbnail = jQuery('#f-thumbnail').prop('files')[0];
      console.log(f_thumbnail);
      //SaveFlyer(f_title, f_validity, f_ID, f_company, f_category, f_thumbnail);
    });

    function SaveFlyer(f_title, f_validity, f_ID, f_company, f_category, f_thumbnail) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
            cache: false,
            contentType: 'json',
            dataType: false,
            data: { 'action':'save_flyer', 'f_title':f_title, 'f_validity':f_validity, 'f_ID':f_ID, 'f_company':f_company, 'f_category':f_category, 'f_thumbnail':f_thumbnail }, 
            beforeSend: onLoading,
            success: onSuccesPing,
            crossDomain:true
        });

    }
    function onLoading() {
    }
    function onSuccesPing(data, status) {
        alert('Success!!');
    }
  });
```

And in my `functions.php`, I have...

```
function save_flyer()
{
    $f_title        = $_POST['f_title'];
    $f_validity   = $_POST['f_validity'];
    $f_ID         = $_POST['f_ID'];
    $f_company    = $_POST['f_company'];
    $f_category   = $_POST['f_category'];
    $f_thumbnail  = $_POST['f_thumbnail'];

    $new_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $f_title,
        'tags_input'    => $f_category,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',       
        'post_type'     => 'soldy-flyer'
    );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);

    add_post_meta($post_id, 'sf_flyer-id', $f_ID);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'sf_flyer-company', $f_company);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'sf_flyer-valid', $f_validity);

    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

    $attahment_id = media_handle_upload( 'f_thumbnail', $post_id );

    set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attahment_id);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_save_flyer', 'save_flyer');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_save_flyer', 'save_flyer');
```

Comment: "contentType" is a the type of content you send then try with `"contentType" : false,`

Comment: @Kaperto I tried but did not work, Thanks brother. is There Anything I can try?

Comment: try without "crossdomain". what I use for years is `$.ajax({"url" : ajaxurl, "type" : "POST", "data" : formData, "processData" : false, "contentType" : false, "dataType"" : "html"})`

Comment: oh, I forget something, to send files use FormData `let formData = new FormData();

formData.append("action", "save_flyer");
formData.append("f_title", f_title);

$.each(jQuery('#f-thumbnail').files, function (i, file) {
 formData.append("f_" + i, file);
});`

Comment: @Kaperto thanks, brother. But the same result as before. Data is not being sent correctly, anyway if 'processData' set to false otherwise error as 'illegal invocation'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload file using ajax using below code:

**First :**
Add attributes `name="f-form"` and `id="f-form"` in your `<form>` tag.

After that, In js script, get form data using `new FormData()` and send to ajax data,

**Note :** change  `url: ajax_object.ajaxurl` with your ajax url path

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    jQuery('#f-submit').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var form = jQuery('#f-form')[0];
      var varform = new FormData(form);
      varform.append("action", "save_flyer");
      SaveFlyer(varform);
    });

    function SaveFlyer(varform) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: varform,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: onLoading,
            success: onSuccesPing,
            crossDomain:true
        });

    }
    function onLoading() {
    }
    function onSuccesPing(data, status) {
        if(data.result == 'true')
        {
            alert('Success!!');
        }
        if(data.result == 'false')
        {
            alert('Fail!!');
        }
    }
  });
```

Finaly, ajax handel request :

```
function save_flyer()
{
    $f_title        = $_POST['f-title'];
    $f_validity   = $_POST['f-validity'];
    $f_ID         = $_POST['f-ID'];
    $f_company    = $_POST['f-company'];
    $f_category   = $_POST['f-category'];

    $new_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $f_title,
        'tags_input'    => $f_category,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',       
        'post_type'     => 'soldy-flyer'
    );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
    if($post_id)
    {
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'sf_flyer-id', $f_ID);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'sf_flyer-company', $f_company);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'sf_flyer-valid', $f_validity);

        if(empty($_FILES['f-thumbnail']['error'])){
          require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
          require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
          require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );

           $attahment_id = media_handle_upload( 'f-thumbnail', $post_id );

          if(!empty($attahment_id))
          { 
             set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attahment_id);
          }
         }   
         $result1 = 'true';
    }
    else
    {
            $result1= 'false';
    }   

     echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result1));
    die();  
}
add_action('wp_ajax_save_flyer', 'save_flyer');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_save_flyer', 'save_flyer');
```

let me know if this helps to you.

Comment: Whats wrong in my answer ? why answer was downvoted ?